# React-Bootstrap nav button issue

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-nav

i am using React-Bootstrap responsive navbar. I want to change the hamburger button's color or change the whole button. how can i change it?

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
    <Nav>
      <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
        Dank memes
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change color using css. You have to change stroke value like stroke='rgba%280, 0, 0, 1%29' for black color:

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%280, 0, 0, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
}
```

Comment: it just ovewrite the previos button which doesnt look good.

Comment: look at this question it will help you: [Bootstrap 4 Change Hamburger Toggler Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586729/bootstrap-4-change-hamburger-toggler-color)

Comment: actually all these answers are for Bootsrap i am talking about react-bootstrap

Comment: In the background react is using  Bootstrap style sheet only. look at this question were font-awesome is used for hamburger icon: [React-Bootstrap: Customize Navbar's hamburger menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208067/react-bootstrap-customize-navbars-hamburger-menu-with-font-awesome-svg)